# BufferedImage texture doesnt appear in java3D

Tags: java, java-3d

I'm quite new in java3D and on stackoverflow. My problem is I try to add a BufferedImage texture to a rectangle, and it doesnt appear. I saved the BufferedImage to a file so I'm sure it's not empty. "bi" is the BufferedImage. It seems anything I can find about java3D is quite outdated. Comments are about the commands above it, not below.

```
    QuadArray alap = new QuadArray(4, QuadArray.COORDINATES | GeometryArray.TEXTURE_COORDINATE_2);

    // [...] setting coordinates for the polygon (rectangle)

    Appearance alapAppearance = new Appearance();
    PolygonAttributes alapPa = new PolygonAttributes();

    alapAppearance.setPolygonAttributes(alapPa);

    alap.setTextureCoordinate (0, 0, new TexCoord2f(0.0f,0.0f));
    alap.setTextureCoordinate (0, 1, new TexCoord2f(1.0f,0.0f));
    alap.setTextureCoordinate (0, 2, new TexCoord2f(1.0f,1.0f));
    alap.setTextureCoordinate (0, 3, new TexCoord2f(0.0f,1.0f));
    //tryed in different order

    TextureAttributes texAttr = new TextureAttributes();
    texAttr.setTextureMode(TextureAttributes.REPLACE);
    TextureLoader loader = new TextureLoader(bi, TextureLoader.ALLOW_NON_POWER_OF_TWO);
    //Tryed with "RGB" flag too (as second parameter).
    Texture t1 = loader.getTexture();

t1.setBoundaryModeS(Texture.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
t1.setBoundaryModeT(Texture.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    alapAppearance.setCapability(Appearance.ALLOW_TEXTURE_WRITE);
    alapAppearance.setCapability(Appearance.ALLOW_TEXTURE_ATTRIBUTES_WRITE);
    //I don't think it's really needed, but can't hurt I quess.
    alapAppearance.setTextureAttributes(texAttr);
    alapAppearance.setTexture(t1);

    tfg.addChild(new Shape3D(alap, alapAppearance));
    //tfg = transformGroup
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found the solution. It seems the TextureLoader.ALLOW_NON_POWER_OF_TWO makes the texture loader to load a texture that has no power of 2 size, but the java3d still wont stretch it on the polygon. Might be a flag somewhere for that too, because it seems to be very pointless to load such texture you are not able to use.